# Using jQuery to switch to focus a tab with a validation error

Tags: jquery, validation, tabs, jquery-validate

I'm trying to get jQuery to switch to a tab if it finds an error on it. Right now it will find an error but won't go to the tab with the error.

This is the code I currently have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#Form').validate({
        ignore: ".ignore",
        invalidHandler: function(){             
            jQuery("#tabs").tabs("select", jQuery("#Form .input-validation-error").closest(".tab-pane").get(0).id);
        }
    });
});

jQuery('.Submit').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#Form').submit()
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery('#userEditForm').validate({
    ignore: ".ignore",
    invalidHandler: function(e, validator){
        if(validator.errorList.length)
        $('#tabs a[href="#' + jQuery(validator.errorList[0].element).closest(".tab-pane").attr('id') + '"]').tab('show')
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eDgEp/)