# Form validation not working for inactive tabs [MVC]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

There is lots of question and answer regarding form validation (client side) for inactive tabs, but however I couldn't do it myself right. I have three tabs on same form and using MVC data annotation, I can validate last tab(active) but it doesn't validate other 2 tabs. Here is my jquery code

```
var SaveUser = function () {                        
        $("#SaveUserForm").validate({
            ignore: ""
            });
        if (!$("#SaveUserForm").valid()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var formdata = new FormData($('#SaveUserForm')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("SaveUser", "UserMenu")",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(d) {
                    if (d.Result === 'true') {
                        alert('success');
                    } else {
                        alert('not success');
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
```

1. Is there any process that could validate inactive tabs as well?
2. How could make error tab focus-able?

Thanks in advance....

**Update** 
Html code for tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#activity" data-toggle="tab">Basic Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#timeline" data-toggle="tab">Login Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Login Time</a></li>
</ul>
```

and Tabs content:

```
<div class="tab-content">
       <div class="tab-pane active" id="activity">
        //Some input fields
       </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">
        //other input fields
       </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
        //Input fields with
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" onclick="SaveUser()"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Save</a>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a single form spanning across 3 tabs or 3 different forms ? your current code is validating only one form i guess ?

Comment: This a single form  with three tabs @Shyju

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935671/attaching-jquery-validation-to-replacement-element/33937362#33937362)  - and remove the `$("#SaveUserForm").validate({ ignore: "" });` code in your `SaveUser` function

Comment: @StephenMuecke I I removed the  '$("#SaveUserForm").validate({ ignore: "" });'  but still it validate only last tab (settings).

Comment: Did you add `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });` as per the answer I linked to?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks it works nice, Is this possible to make error tab/input fields focus-able on other tab?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: @StephenMuecke I mean, If error in first or second tab it automatically open that particular tab. Lets say I have a required field in second tab and I ignore that input field, for now error message appear. what I want to jump on 2nd tab with this error. Similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179148/using-jquery-to-switch-to-focus-a-tab-with-a-validation-error/18179214)

Comment: Only with some javascript (e.g. find elements with class = `input-validation-error`), but I'm not sure it makes sense. If you have an error in multiple tabs, which tab do you want to display? It might be better to validate the form controls in a tab before you go to another tab, and if not valid, prevent leaving the tab

Comment: For an example of validating a group of controls, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)