# Displaying error message depending on tabs containing the error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cshtml containing different tabs and each tabs contain a set of inputs which required validation.

What I want to do is that when I validate the input I display a single error message saying in which tab is the inputs empty.

For example, suppose I have 3 tabs : air, sea, road and that some inputs in all 3 tabs are empty.  I will display an error message saying :  Empty inputs in sea, air and road.
If there are some empty inputs in air only, the error message will be  Empty inputs in air.

I have the following jquery function :

```
    function ValidateRates() {
    var isValid = true;
    elementValidCount = 0
    $(".changeValue").each(function (index) {

        var rateValue = $(this).val();
        if (rateValue == 0 || rateValue =='') {
            elementValidCount++;
        }
    });
    if (elementValidCount > 0) {
        isValid = false;
        $("#emptyRateError").css("display", "flex").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    return isValid;
    }
```

Each input has the class changeValue and the tabs are as follows:

```
<div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
    <a href="#sea-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">SEA<i class="icon-sea"></i><span class="mdl-tabs__ripple-container mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-upgraded=",MaterialRipple"><span class="mdl-ripple is-animating" style="width: 2146.98px; height: 2146.98px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(105px, 20px);"></span></span></a>
</div>
```

Any idea of how I can do this?

Comment: select your active tab name and show the error message.`$("#tabs .ui-tabs-active").text()`

Comment: @Kaushik : No, I don't need the active tab only, but all of them.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle/demo?

Comment: check this if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18179214/2845389